# Take up full page, not just window height

Tags: css

I've heard that using `100vh` will make an element take up the whole browser window. That's true. `100vh` does **not** make the element take up the entire page though. Scroll bars can interfere with this.

Example:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#a {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}

#b {
  flex: 2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b">As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long.</div>
</div>
```

How can I make sure that the background color stays the same for the **entire** page, not just the viewable part at the start?

Comment: consider using a flexbox.

Comment: @DanielA.White How?

Comment: there's plenty of examples online.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space

Comment: @DanielA.White If you know how to solve the problem, could you please provide an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since your text is contained inside of your div, there is no need to specify a height - It will be as large as its content.

```css
#a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. </div>
```

**Edit**

What you want is (as far i know) not possible. What you can do is color the background and use `a` as a placeholder. I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but thats the only solution I can think of.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#a {
  flex: 1;
}

#b {
  flex: 2;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b">As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long. As you can see, this text is very long.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble replicating my issue. See the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Easy just make it `100%` or don't specify a height.

```css
#a {
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. As you can see, this <code>div</code> is very large and will run off the page. Scroll down to see that the background color does not apply further down on the page. </div>
```

Comment: Make the height 100% using percent will scale the whole page